# How to make a new column based on values in new and old table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Given below is the structure of my data

```
Name    Country
s       India
d       Ind
c       Afric
r       Africa
f       Ind
v       India
```

There are many mistakes in the country column. Below is the table containing identified mistakes

```
    Old Value   New Value   Source  Column
Ind India   Avox    Country
Afric   Africa  Avox    Country
```

I need the following table which contains the correct value of Country

```
Name    Country New_Column
s       India   India
d       Ind     India
c       Afric   Africa
r       Africa  Africa
f       Ind     India
v       India   India
```

Given below is the command I am using. This is just the snapsshot of data. My data is very big

```
merge into L03_a_AVOX_DATA_test n using (
    SELECT old_value , new_value
      FROM Transformation_Data_all where column_identifier='Country' and Source_identifier='Avox'
) o ON (n.Country = o.old_value)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  n.New_Column = o.new_value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `DECODE` function to update all the incorrect column values. Or, to make it more explicit and readable, use `CASE` construct.

**Using DECODE**

```
DECODE(column, 'Ind', 'India', 'Afric', 'Africa')
```

**Using CASE**

```
CASE
   WHEN column = 'Ind'
      THEN 'India'
   WHEN column = 'Afric'
      THEN 'Africa'
END
```

So, your update statement would look like,

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
   SET COUNTRY_NAME = <the decode or case expression as explained above>
 WHERE COUNTRY_NAME IN(country names list);
```

Answer (score 0):

The "simple" version: use two updates:

```
update the_table
   set country = 'India'
where country = 'Ind';

update the_table
   set country = 'Africa'
where country = 'Afric;
```

A bit more complicated using a single statement

```
update the_table
   set country = case 
                   when country = 'Afric' then 'Africa'
                   when country = 'Ind' then 'India'
                 end
where country in ('Afric', 'Ind');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "question" doesn't actually feature a question as such.  Perhaps you meant to ask was "why am I getting a compilation error when I try to run this MERGE statement?"  If so, the answer is you need to include the UPDATE key word in the MATCHED clause.

```
merge into L03_a_AVOX_DATA_test n 
using (
    SELECT old_value , new_value
      FROM Transformation_Data_all 
      where column_identifier='Country'
    and Source_identifier='Avox'
   ) o 
   ON (n.Country = o.old_value)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE 
  SET  n.New_Column = o.new_value;
```

If you need to populate the NEW_COLUMN for all rows, as your result set suggests you do, then you can do that with a simple update after running the merge.

```
update 03_a_AVOX_DATA_test n
set n.New_Column = n.Country 
where n.New_Column is null;
```